# how do I make multiple count under having clause

Tags: sql

some sample data:

```
Id    name    value    ref
1     ab      xy
2     aba     z
3     ab      xy
4     abc     def
5     gxr     mdy
```

what I am trying to do is to get the two column that appeared more than once
so row 1 and row 3 would be selected.

```
select name, value from table_x 
where value is not null group by name having count(name) >= 2 
and having count(value) >= 2;
```

got stucked.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. `group by` name and value and check for count >=2 thereafter.

```
select name, value 
from table_x 
where value is not null 
group by name, value 
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

@vkp's answer is correct if you only care about finding the distinct name/value pairs that appear more than once. But if you actually want the individual rows that satisfy the criteria, try this:

```
SELECT  t1.Name, t1.[Value]
FROM    Table_X t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT  Name, [Value]
    FROM    Table_X
    where   [Value] IS NOT NULL
    GROUP   BY Name, [Value]
    HAVING  COUNT(1) >= 2
) t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.[Value] = t2.[Value]
```